# Pass image from main view to another view issue

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm trying to select an image from the image library and pass it to another view after selecting it through `UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage` but it is not working. I always get an empty `UIImageView` in the other page. What could be my issue?

MainPageVeiwController.m:

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo {

    FormViewController *second = [[FormViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FormViewController" bundle:nil];

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    [second.imageView setImage:[editingInfo objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:second animated:YES];
}
```

FormViewController.m:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the view of FormViewController has not loaded yet at the time you try to access imageView, so it will be nil. You should create a UIImage property in FormViewController, and pass the image instead. Let FormViewController populate its own image view in viewDidLoad.

Comment: Thanks for your answer I will check that. and let you know.

Comment: Sorry but how can I put `UIImage` and set `setImage:[editingInfo objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]];` it won't accept it.

Comment: @LuaiKalkatawi, you don't do it that way, just pass the image. Create a UIImage property in FormViewController, lets call it passedInImage for example. In didFinishPickingImage:, say, second.passedInImage = [editingInfo objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];